# use lucene to highlight indexed terms in input query text

Tags: java, lucene

Would it be possible to use lucene to find and highlight indexed terms in query text (let's say a couple of lines), as opposed to the normal usage of highlighting indexed text (again, a couple of lines) with query terms?

For example, given the input query "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", with the terms "fox" and "dog" in the index, the result should be "The quick brown `<b>`fox`</b>` jumps over the lazy `<b>`dog`</b>`".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any Lucene highlighter that does not require the original text - but rather can work on term positions etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784495/is-there-any-lucene-highlighter-that-does-not-require-the-original-text-but-ra)

Comment: I don't see how it is a duplicate, as far as I understand the other question. I don't have the book, so I cannot look up the examples that are discussed. Thanks for the suggestion tho.